# Linked List... doesn't change

Tags: c

This is very simple function to build binnary tree.

I use `Build_tree(first_TR, A);` And it prints
 "added as first, added as first, added as first, added as first, added as first,
added as first, added as first, added as first, added as first, added as first,".

That means `first_TR == 0`. Why? I also tried `Build_tree(&first_TR, A);`
Doesn't work :(

```
typedef struct SElementBST {
    struct SElementBST  *left, *right; /* wskaźnik na kolejny element listy */
    unsigned slowo[DlugoscSlow+1]; /* przechowywana wartość */
}   TBST;

TBST *first_TR = 0; 

void Build_tree(TBST *first, unsigned char array[IloscSlow][DlugoscSlow+1])
{

    int i,k,m;
    TBST *tmp, *parent;

    for(i=0;i<IloscSlow;i++)
    {

        if(!first_TR)   
        {
            first = (TBST*) malloc(sizeof(TBST));
            first -> left = 0;
            first -> right = 0;
            printf("added as first, ");
            for(k=0;k<DlugoscSlow+1;k++)
                    first -> slowo[k] = array[i][k];
        } 
        else
        {
            tmp = first;

            while(tmp != 0)
            {
                k = 0;
                parent = tmp;

                while ((tmp->slowo[k] == array[i][k]) && (k<DlugoscSlow-1))
                               k++;

                if(tmp->slowo[k] < array[i][k]) tmp = tmp -> right;
                else tmp = tmp -> left;

            }

            tmp = (TBST*) malloc(sizeof(TBST));
            tmp -> left = 0;
            tmp -> right = 0;

            for(m=0;m<DlugoscSlow+1;m++)
                tmp-> slowo[m] = array[i][m];

            if(parent->slowo[k] < array[i][k]) parent -> right = tmp;
            else parent -> left = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your formatting is inconsistent. It doesn't have to be perfect, but should look somewhat like the output of a pretty-printer. Also, almost everyone here (and almost every programmer) understands English. Unfortunately, the same cannot be said about any other language, so you should keep variables and comments in that language.

Comment: If what you are building is a BST, why does your question's title mention linked list?

Answer (score 3):

If you have this:

```
void something(type *p) {
  p = somethingelse;
}

int main() {
  type *a = ...;
  something(a);
}
```

The assignment in function `something` will not change the value of `a` in the caller (`main` here). The pointer is passed *by value*, meaning that a copy of the pointer's value is given to function `something`.

If you want to be able to change what `a` points to in the caller, you need to pass a pointer to pointer.

```
void something(type **p) {
 *p = somethingelse;
}

int main() {
 type *a;
 something(&a);
}
```

---

You're not changing `first_TR` anywhere in that code. So it's keeping it's null value all along.

Either you don't need first_TR and your code should be something like:

```
if(!first)  
{
 first = malloc(sizeof(TBST));
 ...
}
```

Or you do need it, and you could do:

```
if(!first_TR)  
{
 first = malloc(sizeof(TBST));
 ...
 first_TR = first;
}
```

(You don't need to cast the result of `malloc` in `C`.)

Comment: In fact, you even [shouldn't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc#Disadvantages_to_casting) cast malloc().